# xterm cannot display unicode

Tags: 14.04, unicode, xterm

My xterm cannot display unicode characters.
Because I've tried a lot of variations of font and such, to ensure that I'm giving full information, here is the full output of my xrdb command.

```
[T400s ~]xrdb -q
*customization: -color
XTerm*fullscreen:       never
xterm*VT100.geometry:   80x25
xterm*dynamicColors:    true
xterm*eightBitInput:    false
xterm*jumpScroll:       true
xterm*locale:           true
xterm*multiScroll:      true
xterm*rightScrollBar:   true
xterm*saveLines:        10000
xterm*scrollBar:        true
xterm*scrollKey:        true
xterm*scrollTtyOutput:  false
xterm*selectToClipboard:true
xterm*toolBar:  true
xterm*utf8:     2  #Also tried with 1
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:       rgb
```

Also tried the following:

```
xterm*faceName:           Monaco:size=13:antialias=true
xterm*font:              -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

And below is the locale command

```
[T400s ~]locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

My xterm command is: `xterm -en utf-8 -u8` and `uxterm`
XTERM_LOCALE inside xterm is `en_US.UTF-8`

Would someone be able to help me how to display unicode in xterm?

PS: My question has more config and less english, but I suppose that's the best way to convey information. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (now)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 13.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Comment: @Fabby I upgraded, can you allow the question to be answered now, please?

Comment: Not all fonts include the entire UNICODE character set.  Could you try with `Envy Code R`, please?

Comment: Should have noted, my font displays the tested UNICODE characters fine otherwise

Comment: Could you post a screen-shot of your problem?

Comment: @Fabby The screen is completely empty. When it should be showing a unicode character

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try `uxterm` which comes with Ubuntu by default, and the man page defines it as x terminal emulator for unicode environments. Here's excerpt from `man uxterm`:

> uxterm is a wrapper around the xterm(1) program that invokes the
>   latter
>          program with the “UXTerm” X  resource  class  set.   All  arguments  to
>          uxterm  are  passed  to  xterm  without  processing; the -class and -u8
>          options should not be specified because they are used by  the  wrapper.

Comment: Should have noted, no luck with uxterm either.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 15.10.
I tried to get vim to display utf-8 characters unsuccessfully. I searched a lot of hours on the web and various threads. I experimented with different .vimrc settings. I then came across a thread that suggested to cat the file to see if it displayed correctly (in xterm or uxterm) which it did not.

> cat junk.txt

So then I searched about xterm and displaying utf-8 characters. This also was unsuccessful. I then mv'd my .Xresources to a different name as to remove this out of the equation of causing the problem.

> mv .Xresources .Xresources.save

After I did this, both cat of the file and the vim editor would display utf-8. You may want to try and see if something in the .Xresources is causing the issue.